# How to use intersecting booleans on single object?

Tags: modifiers

I want to use two intersecting booleans on a sphere (to make holes on north, south, west, east sides) by using either cylinders or elongated spheres. I do this by positioning my cylinder going through the object and applying the first boolean (works fine), then rotating the cylinder 90 degrees to create another boolean cut, but this either leads to the sphere disappearing, or glitches inside the object (e.g. being able to see the inner outer layer of the sphere from certain angles). Is there a fix for this? Thanks.

Comment: You have to use multiple booleans, you can use many when needed.

Comment: Please put your file here

Comment: Use the Boolean modifier with exact solver in 2.91

Comment: Thanks everyone but I found a solution through trial and error (Blender 2.82) soon after posting this by creating a cube, extending each side to make it a cross, using a subdivision surface modifier to make it a rounded cross, then using this as a single boolean object within my sphere.